# Excel based sql query returning date query error

Tags: sql, oracle, date, parameters

Our department has a file with several SQL queries in it.  While it runs on 1 persons laptop, if I attempt to run it, I get an error stating

> ORA - 01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month.

Some brief background perhaps, the query has only 1 parameter, which is to pull values for a given date range.  The dates are in the excel sheet, and the query has the parameters linked up to the correct cells.

Normally it would be 9/30/2013 to 11/3/2013  (catching all mon-sun weeks that include October).  just to rule out error, Ive changed the date range to 10/2 to 10/3.

same error.

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Perhaps the program is expecting 'day/month/year' instead of 'month/day/year'?

Comment: are the parameter fields in the spread sheet date types?

Comment: It runs if I hardcode the dates into the query rather than calling them as paramaters.  As a result, Im certain it is MM/DD/YYYY format.  I have tried converting the excel cell using text(), even going so far as to grab the exact custom formatting that the table has for that column, to ensure its formated properly.  No dice.  sometimes the error says only "invalid month".

Comment: better try with yyyy/MM/dd

Comment: It would seem to me that you're not explicitly specifying your date format in your query and instead relying on the NLS date settings of your installation.